# Visual Studio 2015 и SQL Server Integration Services

Tags: sql, visual-studio, sql-server, package, integration-services

Подскажите, можно ли в Visual Studio 2015 создавать SSIS  пакеты для SQL Server 2008?

Создаю новый проект и мне на выбор только MS SQL Server'а 2012+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нельзя. Ставьте SSMS и Visual Studio из комплекта SQL 2008 или 2008 R2. Или VS 2008 и компоненты для редактирования SSIS пакетов.